# Using glob to locate modules and then importing module dynamically

Tags: python, module, glob

I have several modules I want to import dynamically. The modules are named prefix_? where ? = [0,1,2,3]. I use glob to get a list of the files/modules.

```
module = glob.glob(prefix_?.py)
module.sort()
```

Now I want to import one module at a time and run some code.

```
for m in range(0,len(module),1):
    from module[m] import x, y, z
```

However I can't do this because module is a list of strings. Is there some way to convert the format from being a string to an actual module that I can import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) module:

```
import glob
import importlib
module = glob.glob(prefix_?.py)
module.sort()
for m in module:      #iterate over list itself, why range?
    mod = importlib.import_module(m[:-3]) #strip off .py
```

Comment: I was just gonna edit my post and put importlib in there ... but meh you covered it :P +1

Comment: Thanks this worked. I couldn't import the objects as standalone variables, had to prefix it with mod. but that is good enough. I iterated over range because there were more than 100 files and with random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_module = __import__("some_file") #note you leave off the .py
x = my_module.x
y = my_module.y
....
```

I think thats it anyway